# Redshift Query With Many Rows Always Spills to Disk and Crashes

Tags: amazon-redshift

Running query below on AWS DC2.xlarge instance (10 nodes, 15GB RAM, 1.6 TB HDD).  Tables has 1,732,721,100 rows, but only five columns.  Working memory consumed by the sort step was 22,767,206,400 (23GB).  I realize this exceeds the 15GB of physical memory, but won't Redshift page the sort onto the disk?  There was over 1.2TB of free space in the clusters when the query ran, and I don't understand how a 23 GB sort filled up over 1.2 TB of disk space.  The table columns are optimally encoded, superfluous columns have been dropped, and the sort keys match the partition logic.  Only problem is a very high skewness of the table, but my attempt to unskew also result in a disk spill.`

create table xstg_prof_MED_phase2b as
select *, first_value(_random)
over (partition by subscriber_cd, mbr_cd
order by _random desc
rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
from (select * from xstg_prof_MED_phase2a )
order by subscriber_cd, mbr_cd
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

Can someone please help?  Or does Redshift just hate me?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has more to do with your window function. The way to find out is to run explain on your query and see where the space is being consumed.

The issue is likely the skew. Each node of redshift is a networked computer and has its own memory and dick space. If any one node fills up the query fails. You may need to just deep copy the table before running the query.

Be aware that column encoding only impacts data oon disk. Once it is inflight it is raw (uncompressed). So memory and spill space are consumed by raw data.

In cloudwatch you can monitor each node's space available. If this assessment is correct you will see the table skew result in failure on one node.